# transform each select options value to list of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I have this:

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="label">
    <label for="pa_varnish_color">Цвет лака</label>
   </td>
    <td class="value">
     <select id="pa_varnish_color" name="attribute_pa_varnish_color">
      <option value="">Выбрать вариант…</option>
      <option value="white" class="active">белый</option>
      <option value="caluzhnica" class="active">калужница</option>
      <option value="oregon" class="active">орегон</option>
     </select> </td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="label">
    <label for="pa_type_of_furniture">Тип дерева</label>
   </td>
   <td class="value">
    <select id="pa_type_of_furniture" name="attribute_pa_type_of_furniture">
     <option value="">Выбрать вариант…</option>
     <option value="oak" class="active">Дуб</option>
     <option value="maple" class="active">Клён</option>
     <option value="ash" class="active">Ясень</option>
    </select>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using Jquery i need to transform data from select to ul like this:

```
<ul class="variation-select">
<li></li>
<li>белый</li>
<li>калужница</li>
<li>орегон</li>
</ul>
<ul class="variation-select">
<li></li>
<li>Дуб</li>
<li>Клён</li>
<li>Ясень</li>
</ul>
```

also i can't use select id because i don't know count of select it can be 1 2 3 or more, and also i don't know the name of id because it generated in wordpress panel.
So what i tried by jquery:

```
$(".variations_form .variations select").each(function () {
    $j(".summary").append('<ul class=variation-select>' + $j(this).val() + '</ul>');
    $(this).children("option").each(function () {
        $j(".variation-select").append('<li>' + $j(this).val() + '</li>');
    });
});
```

And finally i got off course false data for me:

```
<ul class="variation-select">
<li></li>
<li>white</li>
<li>caluzhnica</li>
<li>oregon</li>
<li></li>
<li>oak</li>
<li>maple</li>
<li>ash</li>
</ul>
<ul class="variation-select">
<li></li>
<li>oak</li>
<li>maple</li>
<li>ash</li>
</ul>
```

Someone please help me to understand how can i get data of each select in each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are appending `<li>` to all `<ul>` with class `variation-select`, while you need to add `<li>` to only newly created `<ul>`.
- For getting `<option>` inner text instead of its value, you can use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

_

```
$(".variations_form .variations select").each(function()
{
    var newUl = $('<ul class=variation-select>' + $(this).val() + '</ul>');
    $(".summary").append(newUl);
    $(this).children("option").each(function()
    {
        newUl.append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfr30rcp/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much man, I think I have some problem with understanding logic. But i'll try to understand your thought.

Comment: @sanchahous you're welcome. Well, I only replaced `.val()` with `.text()` and saved newly created `<ul>` in local variable for using it in `<li>` appending. So, I hope, there are no hard places to understand.

Answer (score 0):

use $j(this).text()  instead of $j(this).val() and you should be fine.

Comment: This is partly solve my problem. Using $j(this).text() i get true names but it still put all options value from all selects to first ul.
This is the main problem